# cannot install tensorflow-text using pip despite having tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1 installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

My tensorflow 2.0.0beta1 runs normally, but I cannot install tensorflow-text using the command pip install tensorflow-text (as described on the tensorflow page). I can find it using pip search tensorflow-text but I am getting an error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
```

There are no requirements for this package (i.e. a specific python version). 
I am running on windows, using conda, python 3.6.9

Comment: I have tried installing with tensorflow 2.1 and 2.2.0rc2 
neither works on my conda environment. 

I get the following error: 

`` ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text ``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update

The first release candidate of 2.4.0 was published today which features windows wheels for the first time. [2.4.0rc0 on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.4.0rc0/#files). Note that only wheels for Python 3.6 and 3.7 are working properly at the moment. Install via e.g.

```
> py -3.7 -m pip install tensorflow-text==2.4.0rc0
```

#### Original answer

At the time of writing this, `tensorflow-text` is not available for Windows yet.

> Windows is something we do wish to add. We've had some difficulties getting a working package though, which is why it is not available yet. The difference between this library and tensorflow-probability is we make use of custom ops written in c++, and building those shared libraries to work well with Tensorflow inside Windows has had issues; plus, the lengthy build times on Windows has made iterating on these issues slow. While the next beta release (this week) will not include Windows, we would like for the next release to include it.

[Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/44#issuecomment-511615087).

Comment: Is this solved for windows yet? I am not able to install tensorflow-text still with tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: @KumarSaurabh no, the issue is still open. You can subscribe to the issue to receive email updates on the issue status, so you'll be notified once it's resolved.

Comment: Update: not now also.